# Resource handler returned message: "Error occurred while GetObject. S3 Error Code: NoSuchKey. S3 Error Message: The specified key does not exist

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to complete the following AWS automation task.

[text](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-use-amazon-guardduty-and-aws-waf-v2-to-automatically-block-suspicious-hosts/)

I've followed the instructed to a tee. I am stuck on deploying the CloudFormation template.

I keep this error when deploying:

```
Resource handler returned message: "Error occurred while GetObject. S3 Error Code: NoSuchKey. S3 Error Message: The specified key does not exist. (Service: Lambda, Status Code: 400, Request ID:)" (RequestToken:, HandlerErrorCode: InvalidRequest)
```

I have tried to see if anybody else has completed this automation task. But, I can't find anything. I have attached below my S3 bucket details and CloudFormation stack details:

[S3 bucket](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Q3w8.png)
[CloudFormation stack details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VylEG.png)

This is the key bit of YAML that I think might be going wrong:

```
 GuardDutytoACLLambda:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      Description: "GuardDuty to ACL Function"
      Architectures:
        - arm64
      Handler : "guardduty_to_acl_lambda.lambda_handler"
      MemorySize: 1024
      Timeout: 300
      Role: !GetAtt GuardDutytoACLRole.Arn
      Runtime : "python3.9"
      Environment:
        Variables:
          ACLMETATABLE: !Ref GuardDutytoACLDDBTable
          REGIONAL_IP_SET: !Ref RegionalBlocklistIPSetV4
          CLOUDFRONT_IP_SET: !Ref CloudFrontBlocklistIPSetV4
          SNSTOPIC: !Ref GuardDutytoACLSNSTopic
      Code:
        S3Bucket: !Sub ${ArtifactsBucket}
        S3Key: !Sub ${ArtifactsPrefix}guardduty_to_acl_lambda_wafv2.zip
```

Comment: Did you upload the .zip files including guardduty_to_acl_lambda_wafv2.zip to the newly created S3 bucket, as instructed?

Comment: I don't understand. If you click the S3 bucket image I've attached, you should see both the ZIP files have been uploaded.

Comment: Stack Overflow readers don't typically go [clicking on links](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question). If you don't provide the details inline, they often won't view them. Anyhow, what is the value of `${ArtifactsPrefix}`? If it's forward slash then that's incorrect. S3 object keys don't start with a forward slash. A prefix would be something like `animals/dogs/` or `zips/`. If the object is at at the top-level of the bucket then the prefix is empty (not forward slash).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have provided `/` as the S3 prefix for the path to the uploaded artifacts.

Unlike traditional file systems, S3 objects at the root level of the bucket don't have a forward slash prefix, so set it to empty string.

A valid S3 object key could be:

```
myfiles.zip
myfolder/myfiles.zip
```

It won't be:

```
/myfiles.zip
/myfolder/myfiles.zip
```